# Git: synchronize the tags from upstream

Tags: git

I have created a fork ([this](https://github.com/mirko-pagliai/js-cookie), *origin*) of a repository ([this](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), *upstream*).

The only difference between *upstream* and *origin* is [this commit](https://github.com/mirko-pagliai/js-cookie/commit/2b5c20eb2ad3ab624eb3eca5e86f06132cf9b216) two years ago, with which I added the `composer.json` file.
(in essence, the owner of the repository has not given any availability to add that file, so I have created a fork that allows the existence of a package on *Packagist*)

Now the problem is this: new tags and new releases are naturally published in *upstream*.

I would like my fork to have synchronous tags and releases with *upstream*, but with the `composer.json` file present (and thus keeping that commit).

What is the best and easiest way to do it?
The *master* branch of my fork contains that commit, but I can not checkout to the local tag and merge the *master* branch, otherwise the changes already present on the *upstream master* branch will also be added.

```
$ git fetch upstream 
Da https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
 * [nuova tag]       latest        -> latest
 * [nuova tag]       v1.0          -> v1.0
 * [nuova tag]       v1.1          -> v1.1
 * [nuova tag]       v1.2.0        -> v1.2.0
 * [nuova tag]       v1.3.0        -> v1.3.0
 * [nuova tag]       v1.3.1        -> v1.3.1
 * [nuova tag]       v1.4.0        -> v1.4.0
 * [nuova tag]       v1.4.1        -> v1.4.1
 * [nuova tag]       v1.5.0        -> v1.5.0
 * [nuova tag]       v1.5.1        -> v1.5.1
 * [nuova tag]       v2.0.0        -> v2.0.0
 * [nuova tag]       v2.0.0-beta.1 -> v2.0.0-beta.1
 * [nuova tag]       v2.0.1        -> v2.0.1
 * [nuova tag]       v2.0.2        -> v2.0.2
 * [nuova tag]       v2.0.3        -> v2.0.3
 * [nuova tag]       v2.0.4        -> v2.0.4
 * [nuova tag]       v2.1.0        -> v2.1.0
 * [nuova tag]       v2.1.1        -> v2.1.1
 * [nuova tag]       v2.1.2        -> v2.1.2
 * [nuova tag]       v2.1.3        -> v2.1.3
 * [nuova tag]       v2.1.4        -> v2.1.4
 * [nuova tag]       v2.2.0        -> v2.2.0
$ git checkout v2.2.0 
Note: checking out 'v2.2.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD si trova ora a 34f056c Release version 2.2.0
$ git merge master 
Aggiornamento di 34f056c..9a69123
Fast-forward
 Gruntfile.js     | 136 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 LICENSE          |  35 ++++++++++++++++----------------
 README.md        |  29 +++++++++++++++++++++------
 SERVER_SIDE.md   |   6 +++---
 composer.json    |  13 ++++++++++++
 package.json     |   4 ++--
 src/js.cookie.js |  73 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------------------
 test/tests.js    |  23 +++++++++++++++++----
 test/utils.js    |   8 +++++++-
 9 files changed, 177 insertions(+), 150 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 composer.json
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wonder why its not working anymore, it was working in the past. Did packagist changed their logic recently and check for composer.json in each tag and before only in master?

Nevertheless two possible solutions for this problem which just came to my mind. Maybe somebody else also have another idea.

**Solution 1 - Fixing the tags**

Here a bash script to add the commit with the composer.json to all tags.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TAGS=`git tag -l`
# this is the commit hash from the point where you added composer.json. Its actually the correct one, I used your repo.
COMMIT="2b5c20eb2ad3ab624eb3eca5e86f06132cf9b216"

for TAG in $TAGS; do
   # Checkout tag
   git checkout $TAG
   # Apply composer.lock commit
   git cherry-pick $COMMIT
   # Remove old tag
   git tag -d $TAG
   # Create new tag
   git tag $TAG
   # Remove tag on origin
   git push origin :$TAG
   # Add tag to origin
   git push origin $TAG
done
```

Problem with this script it always changes all tags. So now it would be okay, next time you merge upstream into your branch, this script needs to be changed to only update the new tags from upstream.

Also it gets messy if you need to change the composer.json at one point and you do not have one commit anymore.

**Solution 2 - Merge with components**

For bootstrap we are using components/bootstrap. Components has shim repositories for some js libs and provide packages for different package managers.

Maybe creating an issue there or ask if they can help you with the workflow they are using. From what I see their shim repos are not a 1:1 clone as its really only the end result. In case of bootstrap it adds compiled css files and removes all files and configs needed to compile it (e.g. babelrc, travis). So it seems pretty custom for each lib. Probably they have different bash script for each lib, which is checking for new releases each day and update their shim repo.

See https://github.com/components/components

And you can compare https://github.com/components/bootstrap with https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Maybe with or without components you could write a own script, which is more or less doing things like they do - check for new tags, if new tag, checkout tag; copy js file to our repo, add composer.json there; commit; create and push tag in your repo.

**Workaround**

If somebody is searching for a workaround till this is fixed, here a working composer.json which is using the original repo directly:

```
{
  "name": "xxx/yyy",
  "description": "xxxx",
  "type": "xxxx",
  "license": "GPL-3.0+",
  "require":{
    "js-cookie/js-cookie": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "js-cookie/js-cookie",
        "version": "2.2.0",
        "source": {
          "url": "https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie.git",
          "type": "git",
          "reference": "v2.2.0"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Biggest disadvantage here is that you manually have to check and change the version. Thats why this is not a solution only a workaround currently.